# efficiently find bit positions in binary strings in a numpy array

Tags: python, string, numpy, binary, pandas

I have a large Pandas dataframe (a subclass of Numpy `ndarray` for most purposes) containing binary strings (0s and 1s).  I need to find the positions of all the zeros in these strings and then label them. Also, I expect the positions of the zeros to be **relatively sparse** (~1% of all bit positions).

Basically, I want to run something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.Series([ '11101110', '11111101' ], ) # start with strings
x = pd.Series([ 0b11101110, 0b11111101 ], ) # ... or integers of a known bit length

zero_positions = find_zero_positions( x )
```

Yielding `zero_positions =`...

```
         value
row bit
0   4        0
    0        0
1   1        0
```

I've tried a few different ways to do this, but haven't come up with anything better than looping through one row at a time. (*EDIT:* The actual strings I want to look at are much longer than the 8-bit examples here, so a lookup table won't work.)

I'm not sure whether it will be more efficient to approach this as a string problem (Pandas's [Vectorized string methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods) don't offer a substring-position-finding method) or a numeric problem (using something like [`numpy.unpackbits`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html), maybe?).

Comment: If you're just looking for zero bits in bytes, why not use a lookup table?

Comment: Good point, @gnibbler. Actually, the input strings I really want to use are much longer (128 bits) making a lookup table impractical.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`numpy.unpackbits`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html) as follows,  starting with an ndarray of this form:

```
In [1]: x = np.array([[0b11101110], [0b11111101]], dtype=np.uint8)

In [2]: x
Out[2]:
array([[238],
       [253]], dtype=uint8)

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.unpackbits(x, axis=1))

In [4]: df.columns = df.columns[::-1]

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
   7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  0
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1
```

Then from the DataFrame, just [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and find the zeros:

```
In [6]: s = df.stack()

In [7]: s.index.names = ['row', 'bit']

In [8]: s[s == 0]
Out[8]:
row  bit
0    4      0
     0      0
1    1      0
dtype: uint8
```

*I think this would be a reasonably efficient method.*

Comment: This works well, although `numpy.unpackbits` only seems to work on 8-bit integers.

I'm not sure about the best way to store 128-bit integers in `ndarray`, much less to convert them to 8-bit chunks (using [`np.frombuffer`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html) introduces some issues with endianness).

Now I'm thinking that my *real* problem may be more with how I get these large bit-strings into Pandas, rather than how I parse them down afterwards...

Comment: @Dan That's annoying, it made for an elegant solution (for uint8s)... :s

Answer (score 1):

One good solution would be to split the input into smallish chunks and use that in a memoized lookup table (where you compute the first time through).

E.g., if each number/array is 128 bits; break it into eight 16-bits parts that are looked up in a table.  At worst, the lookup table needs 2<sup>16</sup> ~ 65536 entries - but if zeros are very sparse (e.g., at most two zeros in any group of 8 bits only need about ~64).  Depending on how sparse you can beef up the size of the chunk.

Answer (score 1):

In the "yuck" department, I would like to enter the following contestant:

```
def numpyToBinString(numpyValue):
    return "".join( [str((numpyValue[0] >> shiftLength) & 1 ) for shiftLength in range(numpyValue.dtype.itemsize * 8)] )
```

Works for shape (,) ndArrays, but could be extended with @vectorize decorator.

Comment: As a followup, it looks like you want to be playing with the [bitArray](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/) package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lookup table.

Create a table that has the 0 positions for each number from 0-255 and a function to access it, call it `zeroBitPositions`, this returns a list.

Then, assuming that you are storing your numbers as a python long type (which, I believe has unlimited precision). You can do the following:

```
allZeroPositions = []
shift = 0
while (num >> shift) > 0:
    zeroPositions += [x + shift for x in zeroBitPositions ((num >> shift) & 0xFF)]
    shift += 8
```

Hopefully this is a good start.